# How can I prevent an iframe from trying to use the javascript of the parent page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to embed [this gallery (warning, nude art content)](http://www.allenamistral.com/Play_Site/JSReplaceContent/forsale.html) in to a webpage using frames.

The problem that I have is that I have a dropdown menu that uses javascript to fade the pages in and out.This is conflicting with the javascript in the gallery. To see the gallery functioning in the site, you can [click here](http://www.allenamistral.com/Play_Site/JSReplaceContent/) and scroll over gallery and click "for sale." It works perfectly in Chrome and Safari. In Firefox, it won't let the images scroll at the bottom, so they stack. I know that this has something to do with line 15 of the gallery below code, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Code for the gallery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.AllenaMistral.com/Play_Site/JSReplaceContent/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery.noConflict();
                (function($) {
        $(window).load(function() {
            sliderLeft=$('#thumbScroller .container').position().left;
            padding=$('#outer_container').css('paddingRight').replace('px', '');
            sliderWidth=$(window).width()-padding;
            $('#thumbScroller').css('width',sliderWidth);
            var totalContent=0;
            $('#thumbScroller .content').each(function () {
                totalContent+=$(this).innerWidth();
                $('#thumbScroller .container').css('width',totalContent);
            });
            $('#thumbScroller').mousemove(function(e){
                if($('#thumbScroller  .container').width()>sliderWidth){
                    var mouseCoords=(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
                    var mousePercentX=mouseCoords/sliderWidth;
                    var destX=-(((totalContent-(sliderWidth))-sliderWidth)*(mousePercentX));
                    var thePosA=mouseCoords-destX;
                    var thePosB=destX-mouseCoords;
                    var animSpeed=600; //ease amount
                    var easeType='easeOutCirc';
                    if(mouseCoords==destX){
                        $('#thumbScroller .container').stop();
                    }
                    else if(mouseCoords>destX){
                        //$('#thumbScroller .container').css('left',-thePosA); //without easing
                        $('#thumbScroller .container').stop().animate({left: -thePosA}, animSpeed,easeType); //with easing
                    }
                    else if(mouseCoords<destX){
                        //$('#thumbScroller .container').css('left',thePosB); //without easing
                        $('#thumbScroller .container').stop().animate({left: thePosB}, animSpeed,easeType); //with easing
                    }
                }
            });
            var fadeSpeed=200;
                            $('#thumbScroller  .thumb').each(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 0.6);
            });

            $('#thumbScroller .thumb').hover(
            function(){ //mouse over
                $(this).fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 1);
            },
            function(){ //mouse out
                $(this).fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 0.6);
            }
        );
        });
        $(window).resize(function() {
            //$('#thumbScroller .container').css('left',sliderLeft); //without easing
            $('#thumbScroller .container').stop().animate({left: sliderLeft}, 400,'easeOutCirc'); //with easing
            $('#thumbScroller').css('width',$(window).width());
            sliderWidth=$(window).width();
        });
                    })(jQuery);
    </script></head>
<body>
<h1 style="font: Open Sans">For Sale Pieces</h1>
    <div id="fp_gallery" class="fp_gallery">
        <img src="full_images/torso1.png" alt="" class="fp_preview" style="display:none;"/>
        <div id="fp_loading" class="fp_loading"></div>
        <div id="fp_next" class="fp_next"></div>
        <div id="fp_prev" class="fp_prev"></div>
        <div id="outer_container">
            <div id="thumbScroller">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div><a href="#"><img src="thumbs/tthumb1.jpg" alt="full_images/torso1.png" class="thumb" /></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fp_thumbtoggle" class="fp_thumbtoggle">View Thumbs</div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>

    <!-- The JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.AllenaMistral.com/Play_Site/JSReplaceContent/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();

        (function($) {
        $(function() {
            //current thumb's index being viewed
            var current         = -1;
            //cache some elements
            var $btn_thumbs = $('#fp_thumbtoggle');
            var $loader     = $('#fp_loading');
            var $btn_next       =$('#fp_next');
            var $btn_prev       = $('#fp_prev');
            var $thumbScroller  = $('#thumbScroller');

            //total number of thumbs
            var nmb_thumbs      = $thumbScroller.find('.content').length;

            //preload thumbs
            var cnt_thumbs      = 0;
            for(var i=0;i<nmb_thumbs;++i){
                var $thumb = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(i+1)+')');
                $('<img/>').load(function(){
                    ++cnt_thumbs;
                    if(cnt_thumbs == nmb_thumbs)
            //display the thumbs on the bottom of the page
            showThumbs(2000);
                }).attr('src',$thumb.find('img').attr('src'));
            }


            //make the document scrollable
            //when the the mouse is moved up/down
            //the user will be able to see the full image
            makeScrollable();

            //clicking on a thumb...
            $thumbScroller.find('.content').bind('click',function(e){
                var $content= $(this);
                var $elem   = $content.find('img');
                //keep track of the current clicked thumb
                //it will be used for the navigation arrows
                current     = $content.index()+1;
                //get the positions of the clicked thumb
                var pos_left    = $elem.offset().left;
                var pos_top     = $elem.offset().top;
                //clone the thumb and place
                //the clone on the top of it
                var $clone  = $elem.clone()
                .addClass('clone')
                .css({
                    'position':'fixed',
                    'left': pos_left + 'px',
                    'top': pos_top + 'px'
                }).insertAfter($('BODY'));

                var windowW = $(window).width();
                var windowH = $(window).height();

                //animate the clone to the center of the page
                $clone.stop()
                .animate({
                    'left': 410 + 'px',
                    'top': windowH/2 + 'px',
                    'margin-left' :-$clone.width()/2 -5 + 'px',
                    'margin-top': -$clone.height()/2 -5 + 'px'
                },500,
                function(){
                    var $theClone   = $(this);
                    var ratio       = $clone.width()/120;
                    var final_w     = 400*ratio;

                    $loader.show();

                    //expand the clone when large image is loaded
                    $('<img class="fp_preview"/>').load(function(){
                        var $newimg         = $(this);
                        var $currImage  = $('#fp_gallery').children('img:first');
                        $newimg.insertBefore($currImage);
                        $loader.hide();
                        //expand clone
                        $theClone.animate({
                            'opacity'       : 0,
                            'top'           : windowH/2 + 'px',
                            'left'          : windowW/2 + 'px',
                            'margin-top'    : '-200px',
                            'margin-left'   : -final_w/2 + 'px',
                            'width'         : final_w + 'px',
                            'height'        : '400px'
                        },1000,function(){$(this).remove();});
                        //now we have two large images on the page
                        //fadeOut the old one so that the new one gets shown
                        $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                        //show the navigation arrows
                        showNav();
                    }).attr('src',$elem.attr('alt'));
                });
                //hide the thumbs container
                hideThumbs();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            //clicking on the "show thumbs"
            //displays the thumbs container and hides
            //the navigation arrows
            $btn_thumbs.bind('click',function(){
                showThumbs(500);
                hideNav();
            });

            function hideThumbs(){
                $('#outer_container').stop().animate({'bottom':'-200px'},500);
                showThumbsBtn();
            }

            function showThumbs(speed){
                $('#outer_container').stop().animate({'bottom':'-20px'},speed);
                hideThumbsBtn();
            }

            function hideThumbsBtn(){
                $btn_thumbs.stop().animate({'bottom':'-120px'},500);
            }

            function showThumbsBtn(){
                $btn_thumbs.stop().animate({'bottom':'-20px'},500);
            }

            function hideNav(){
                $btn_next.stop().animate({'left':'-50px'},500);
                $btn_prev.stop().animate({'left':'-50px'},500);
            }

            function showNav(){
                $btn_next.stop().animate({'left':'772px'},500);
                $btn_prev.stop().animate({'left':'0px'},500);
            }

            //events for navigating through the set of images
            $btn_next.bind('click',showNext);
            $btn_prev.bind('click',showPrev);

            //the aim is to load the new image,
            //place it before the old one and fadeOut the old one
            //we use the current variable to keep track which
            //image comes next / before
            function showNext(){
                ++current;
                var $e_next = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child('+current+')');
                if($e_next.length == 0){
                    current = 1;
                    $e_next = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child('+current+')');
                }
                $loader.show();
                $('<img class="fp_preview"/>').load(function(){
                    var $newimg         = $(this);
                    var $currImage      = $('#fp_gallery').children('img:first');
                    $newimg.insertBefore($currImage);
                    $loader.hide();
                    $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){$(this).remove();});
                }).attr('src',$e_next.find('img').attr('alt'));
            }

            function showPrev(){
                --current;
                var $e_next = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child('+current+')');
                if($e_next.length == 0){
                    current = nmb_thumbs;
                    $e_next = $thumbScroller.find('.content:nth-child('+current+')');
                }
                $loader.show();
                $('<img class="fp_preview"/>').load(function(){
                    var $newimg         = $(this);
                    var $currImage      = $('#fp_gallery').children('img:first');
                    $newimg.insertBefore($currImage);
                    $loader.hide();
                    $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){$(this).remove();});
                }).attr('src',$e_next.find('img').attr('alt'));
            }

            function makeScrollable(){
                $(document).bind('mousemove',function(e){
                    var top = (e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop()/2) ;
                    $(document).scrollTop(top);
                });
            }
        });

        })(jQuery);
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the code for the javascript tags and a sample of how they're being used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
// Hide div 2 by default
$('#wrapper2').show(); 
$('#faces').hide();
$('#hands').hide();
$('#torso').hide();
$('#about').hide();
$('#contact').hide();
$('#collab').hide();
$('#newgallery').hide();
$('.forsale').hide();
$('#calendar').hide();
});  

});



</script>
```

I'm sorry if this is a repeat of another question. I tried looking over and over again and couldn't find something that would make it work perfectly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I have to remove the javascript fading on the main page, I will, but I was really hoping for a workaround that works without removing this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! It will probably help you get a good answer if you can edit your question down so that it focuses more on the exact question you need help with, rather than on the scope of your project as a whole. Good luck!

Comment: That's a lot of hiding...I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing that.

Comment: Thanks, buildsucceeded! I appreciate the input. TymeJV, I'm sure you're right, however I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Huge question is huge. Narrow it down, no one likes to read through megabytes of code.

Comment: Madara, I tried to reduce it to only the pieces that are necessary.